# Camel cxfrs RESTful client / ProducerTemplate ConnectionTimeout

Tags: rest, apache-camel, cxf, cxfrs

I am trying to set the 'connectionTimeout' for a Camel CXF-RS component [here](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html) which produces a RESTful requests on a 3rd party service. The default `30000` miliseconds is to long.

```
Exchange exchange = template.send("cxfrs://" + url, new Processor() {
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
  Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();
  setupDestinationURL(inMessage);
  // using the http central client API
  inMessage.setHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_RS_USING_HTTP_API, Boolean.TRUE);
  // set the Http method
  inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "PUT");
  // set the relative path
  inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, url);                
  // Specify the response class , cxfrs will use InputStream as the response                 object type 
  inMessage.setHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_RS_RESPONSE_CLASS, Customer.class);
  // set a customer header
  inMessage.setHeader("key", "value");
  // since we use the Get method, so we don't need to set the message body
  inMessage.setBody(null);                
 }
});
```

I have tried adding this to our `application-context` as many have suggested, but cannot see it modifying the default values when debugging through the `HTTPConduit` and `HTTPClientPolicy` classes:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
  <http-conf:client ConnectionTimeout="5000"/>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

and I have tried appending

```
 "?httpClientAPI=true&connectionTimeout=5000"
```

as options to the url string.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `http-conf:conduit` element in `application-context` as you did is the way to go and should work. What makes you say it does not?

Quite often a backend server take too long to answer, *after* the connection is made; in this case setting `ReceiveTimeout` is as important as `ConnectionTimeout`.

This is a sample camel Route which consumes RS requests and calls a third-party RS server; the ReceiveTimeout and ConnectionTimeout parameters work as expected.

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsFrontServer" address="..." serviceClass="..."/>

<cxf:rsClient id="rsBackendClient" address=".../" serviceClass="..."/>

<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client ReceiveTimeout="5000" ConnectionTimeout="5000"/>
</http-conf:conduit>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="front">
        <from uri="cxfrs:bean:rsFrontServer"/>
        <!-- do stuff -->
        <to uri="cxfrs:bean:rsBackendClient"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```