# How to set timeout to cxf:rsClient with CAMEL-CXF" camel-2.10.0.redhat-60024"

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have a bundle on jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024. It routes a message to a web service using CXF like this:

```
from("direct-vm:from").id("myfrom").to("bean:bean").inOut(myClient)
```

Timeout for this connection is 30 seconds by default. Question is how can I decrease the timeout value on the client side?

here is my blueprint.xml:

```
<cxf:rsClient 
    id="myClient" address="${my.url}" loggingFeatureEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: don't you mean `cxf:bean:myclient`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Camel cxfrs RESTful client / ProducerTemplate ConnectionTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133777/camel-cxfrs-restful-client-producertemplate-connectiontimeout)

Comment: Yes, I mean cxf:bean:myclient.

Comment: Did you checkout the `conduit` example on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133777/camel-cxfrs-restful-client-producertemplate-connectiontimeout